# Backdrop like Container in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I have a Backdrop like Container (Container with rounded corners). If as a child is a Text, everything is fine. However, if child is e.g. Image, it covers whole container (even the corners).

My build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: buildAppBar("", context),
        body: new Container(
            color: Colors.brown,
            child: Material(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(16.0),
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(16.0)),
              elevation: 12.0,
              child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image(image: NetworkImage('url')),
                  ]),
            )));
  }
```

How to do that image will be inside the radius corner?

Comment: I've edited my answer - there is another solution without `ClipRRect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0), topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
        child: Image(image: NetworkImage('url'))),
```

**UPD**
Found another solution - `Clip.antiAlias` in `Card`:

```
Material(
      child:  Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0), topRight: Radius.circular(16.0))),
        child: Image(image: NetworkImage('url')),
        elevation: 12.0,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thank, but the same problem shows if the child is Container, TabBar etc. It must have some better solution

Comment: So you can put Container or TabBar inside ClipRRect. I think, I don't understand your problem

Comment: Your solution is acceptable, but I would like to have elevation (it is the reason I want to use Material)

Comment: You can put ClipRRect inside Material

Comment: Thanks, that's I looked for.